# Jboss5.1 integrating with remote ActiveMQ

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jms, activemq-classic, jboss5.x

I have two systems:

1. jboss 5.1
2. Active MQ on remote system(windows)

Does the jboss capable of lookup onto the MQ and listen to messages?

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes JBoss is capable of looking up messages on a remote messaging platform like ActiveMQ or IBM MQSeries.

The way the integration works is through Resource Adapters that is based on standard JCA. Each of these remote Messaging platforms provide a Resource Adapter for processing Inbound messages.

Specifically for ActiveMQ I find [this](http://activemq.apache.org/jboss-integration.html) & [this](http://activemq.apache.org/integrating-apache-activemq-with-jboss.html) quite helpful.

Hope this helps you.

Good luck!